# Adding defaults to column headers in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a script which imports data in tables from other websites. The tables are between 5 and 15 columns wide and arbitrarily long.

After I've got the raw data I want the opportunity to make sure my guesses about the column headers are correct. So I want to have a  at the top with a list of the 15 things a column could be called. That way I can quickly correct any poor decisions made by my automatic code.

So the auto code generates 2 arrays, the first of strings:
possible_headers = ["one", "two", "three"...]
The second of indexes into that first array
likely_headers = [2, 0, 5...]
(the columns headers would be "three" then "one" then "six")

And use them like this in my template:

```
{% for likely_head in likely_headers %}
<th>

  <select name="colHeader">
  {% for poss_head in possible_headers %}

    {% if forloop.counter0 == likely_headers.forloop.parentloop.counter0 %}
      <option value="Col:{{forloop.counter0}}" selected>{{poss_head}}</option>
    {% else %}
      <option value="Col:{{forloop.counter0}}">{{poss_head}}</option>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
</select>

</th>

{% endfor %}
```

With the idea that the likely header will be the selected/default item in the select input. Problem is the:

```
likely_headers.forloop.parentloop.counter0
```

Doesn't evaluate. forloop.parentloop.counter0 works correctly but apparently it cannot be used as an index into a list.

I'm new to django so I'm probably doing it all wrong, please be nice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you're using `likely_headers.forloop.parentloop.counter0` when you should use `forloop.parentloop.counter0` according to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

You may also try solving it by encapsulating counter with `{% with %}` tag

```
{% for likely_head in likely_headers %}
  {% with forloop.counter0 as parent_counter %}
    {% for poss_head in possible_headers %}
       {{ parent_counter }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't checked that it works for sure but I think it should.

Also you're probably trying to solve problem that should not be solved in templates. You can try using tags, processing headers in view (using library?) and just returning list of headers that should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The list of integers I thought I had was in truth a list of strings ["1", "5", "3"] so they failed comparison to the for loop iterator. Creating a real list of ints solved the problem.